# Replace a string with variable number of spaces with replaceAll

Tags: java, regex, string

I need to replace a string that could have one or more blank space in its content (at a fixed position) with another string.

e.g:

```
[   string   ]
```

must be replaced with:

```
anotherstring
```

(where there could be more or less or none blank spaces between " and string). And also the replacement must be case insenitive. Actually i'm using that expression:

```
myString.replaceAll("[(?i)string]", "anotherstring");
```

but this only works if there aren't spaces between brackets and string. 
How can i build an expression to consider also whitespaces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to allow any whitespace use:

```
myString.replaceAll("\\[\\s*(?i)string\\s*\\]", "anotherstring");
```

If you want to allow only spaces use:

```
myString.replaceAll("\\[ *(?i)string *\\]", "anotherstring");
```

Note that you've not escaped the `[` and `]` in your regex. `[` and `]` are regex meta-characters that mark the start and end of a character class respectively.

So a `[(?i)string]` matches a single character that is one of `(`, `?`, `i`, `)`, `s`, `t`, `r`, `i`, `n` or `g`

To match them literally they need to be escaped by placing a `\\` before them.

Answer (score 3):

That expression doesn't work, it only has one character class and would match a single character. You need `"(?i)\\[\\s*string\\s*\\]"`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the regular expressions to match the spaces as well, that is a whitespace followed by a * which matches any number of instances of the whitespace, including no whitespace. If you need at least one whitespace, you can replace those with a + sign.

Here's the code for your case:

```
String myString="[      String      ]";
String result = myString.replaceAll("\\[ *(?i)string *\\]", "anotherstring");
```